# How to find closest number from a given value using lamba expression with java8 when i receive an Iterable from the parameter?

Tags: java, java-8, iterable

Like with a List you can type:

```
public Iterable<Integer> findClosestNumbers(int givenValue, Iterable<Integer> numbers, int n){
    Iterable<Integer> closestNumbers;

    int closest = numbers.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - value)))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No value present"));


   return closestNumbers;
```

The 'givenValue' represents the value it should be closest to

The 'numbers' could be an array of numbers {1, 2, 4, 5}

The 'n' specifies how many numbers that should be returned closest to the value

Like value:6 and n=2  then results should return Iterable {4, 5}

How to write this using Iterable as short as possible? I can not change the parameters

Comment: Either create a stream from the iterable (see the linked question), or use a regular loop and a local variable for the current closest value.

Comment: Note that for signed integers, the distance between two `int` values can be larger than the `int` value space. And once `i - value` has overflown, `abs` can’t cure that. As a corner case, if the distance happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the result of `Math.abs` may even be negative. Your approach works fine, as long as the numbers are rather small…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a collection of `n` closest values, you will need to sort and slice the result:

```
public Iterable<Integer> findClosestNumbers(int givenValue, 
          Iterable<Integer> numbers, int n) {

    return StreamSupport.stream(numbers.spliterator(), false)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - givenValue)))
            .limit(n)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will return `n` (or fewer) numbers in ascending order of their distance from `givenValue`.

Comment: Thanks! What if there is 2 numbers equally close to given value and i only want the smalles e.g value=5, n=1, but closest= 4 and 6?

Comment: @RossoTheMan then use `Comparator.<Integer>comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - givenValue)).thenComparing(i -> i)`

Comment: nevemind it already does with your solution!

Comment: The code in the answer would return the first one in the iterable when the distance from `givenValue` is the same. You'd have to add that `thenComparing` if you want the smaller of two values at the same distance of it (try `findClosestNumbers(4, Arrays.asList(1, 5, 3, 0, 2, 6), 1)` with both versions, you'll see).